# Global_Asax Application_Error Fired instead of default IIS7 404 Page Not Found Page

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis-7, global-asax, custom-error-pages

I have a Web Application which has Global_Asax and a Custom Error Page. When user tries to enter to an invalid page which doesn't exist, Application_Error is fired in Global_asax and exception is logged which isn't really an exception (You can see the exception details below). I don't want to handle this case in global_asax but rather in IIS. I've also tried to enter invalid paths ending with .asp and .html and they work fine(They don't end in global_asax but rather in default 404 page).

I need to know which setting I have to change from IIS7 Manager.

Any help would be appreciated.

> Error - The file '/restricted/ff.aspx'
>   does not exist.
>
> System.Web.HttpException: The file
>   'test.aspx' does not exist.  at
>   System.Web.UI.Util.CheckVirtualFileExists(VirtualPath
>   virtualPath)  at
>   System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GetVPathBuildResultInternal(VirtualPath
>   virtualPath, Boolean noBuild, Boolean
>   allowCrossApp, Boolean
>   allowBuildInPrecompile)  at
>   System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GetVPathBuildResultWithNoAssert(HttpContext
>   context, VirtualPath virtualPath,
>   Boolean noBuild, Boolean
>   allowCrossApp, Boolean
>   allowBuildInPrecompile)  at
>   System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GetVirtualPathObjectFactory(VirtualPath
>   virtualPath, HttpContext context,
>   Boolean allowCrossApp, Boolean
>   noAssert)  at
>   System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.CreateInstanceFromVirtualPath(VirtualPath
>   virtualPath, Type requiredBaseType,
>   HttpContext context, Boolean
>   allowCrossApp, Boolean noAssert)  at
>   System.Web.UI.PageHandlerFactory.GetHandlerHelper(HttpContext
>   context, String requestType,
>   VirtualPath virtualPath, String
>   physicalPath)  at
>   System.Web.HttpApplication.MaterializeHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
>   at
>   System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep
>   step, Boolean& completedSynchronously)

Comment: I am having the same problem.  I defined a custom 404 page in my web.config and it's only being applied for non .aspx files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try one of these:

1. Edit the *web.config* file for custom errors:

   ```xml
   <customErrors mode="On">
       <error statusCode="404" redirect="404.aspx"/>
   </customErrors>
   ```
2. Add a `404.aspx` page and set the status code to *404*:

   ```
   public partial class _04 : System.Web.UI.Page
   {
       protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
       {
           Response.StatusCode = 404;
       }
   }
   ```

If it doesn't help you try this as well (it might be reset by your masterpage):

```
protected override void Render(HtmlTextWriter writer)
{
    base.Render(writer);
    Response.StatusCode = 404;
}
```